# How to not change value in computed field

Tags: entities

I have a field created with [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module, the field generate a unique id with `uniqid()` php function.
It's work fine but when I edit contents, value of the field changes to a new value!

I use this field to create tracking number for user requests.
How can I lock the field to not give a new value on edit form?

Comment: Have you tried to add a line to the computed field's code that only sets the value if the node is new?

Comment: @PatrickKenny thank you for reply, no, just generate a unique id in a variable and set to value, how to check if node is new, not set value?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `hook_form_alter` then following will help

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */

function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#node'] && $form['#node']->type .'_node_form' === $form_id) {
    // Is node form.

    if (empty($form['#node']->nid)) {
      // This is a new node
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the config of your computed field, in the section: "`Code (PHP) to compute the text value`", add the following code:

```
//We check if the node is new
if ($entity->isNew()) {
$value = uniqid();
}
//else, we get the value of the computed field of the node
else {
 $node= Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($entity->id());
 $value = $node->field_computed->value;
}
```

***Note***: change the "`field_computed`" for your field machine name.